# node.async parallel : can we create dynamic texts to denote tasks?

Tags: node.js, node-async

Inside node async methods, we define tasks as "one" or "two" like in the example below. Is there a way to make that text dynamic ?

```
    var async = require("async");
    async.parallel({
        one: function(callback){
            setTimeout(function(){
                callback(null, 1);
            }, 200);
        },
        two: function(callback){
            setTimeout(function(){
                callback(null, 2);
            }, 100);
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        console.log(results); // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2} 
    });
```

Comment: This question makes me wonder if there is a larger problem you are trying to solve, using this as a solution.  If this is the case, including that larger problem in your question can help folks provide better answers, including possibly solutions that take a very different approach!

Comment: I am trying to populate the results object with a json which can then be used for further processing. In doing that, I am trying to keep the json fields configurable. So I am wondering if there is a way to do that. For example if the results object contains the json {a=12, b=15}, then I want to populate a & b dynamically through some values saved in my configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [@Castaglia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531816/node-async-parallel-can-we-create-dynamic-texts-to-denote-tasks#comment58753154_35531816) that you would probably benefit by providing more detail about what you are trying to do. That said, I will simply answer the question as stated.

Yes, it is possible to compute the keys of the object dynamically. This applies to any object, not just the one you pass to `async.parallel()`. Perhaps the most elegant solution available in Node is to utilize a new ES2015 feature: [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```
'use strict';

const async = require('async');

function dynmaicAsync(fnOne, fnTwo) {
  async.parallel({
    [fnOne](callback) { ... },
    [fnTwo](callback) { ... }
  },
  (err, results) => console.log(results));
}

dynmaicAsync('un', 'deux');
// { un: 1, deux: 2}
```

The example above also uses the ES2015 [shorthand method definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), which spares us from having to use the `function` keyword for method definitions on object literals.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use these ES2015 features, you can just do something like this:

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async');

function dynmaicAsync(fnOne, fnTwo) {
  var fns = {};
  fns[fnOne] = function { ... };
  fns[fnTwo] = function { ... };
  async.parallel(fns, function(err, results) { ... });
}
```

Comment: I am trying to populate the results object with a json which can then be used for further processing. In doing that, I am trying to keep the json fields configurable. So I am wondering if there is a way to do that. For example if the results object contains the json {a=12, b=15}, then I want to populate a & b dynamically through some values saved in my configuration files.  This solution worked. Thank you very much.